# How to make a table top flag in blender

Tags: objects

I want to make a small flag without animation like this

How to make a shape for flag and connect it to pole
[image]

Comment: What did you try and where did you fail?  ... Add Plane, Subdivide, Assign a vertex group to a one side of selected vertices, add Cloth modifier and under Physics Properties > Cloth > Shape > Pin Group choose your vert. group. Enable self-collision. Play anim to see sim ... https://imgur.com/EN4Myxy

Comment: Search youtube for Blender flag tutorials.  BlenderGuru, at least, has one. While they're for large flags, you can adapt the process to smaller flags.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

1. Create a cylinder for the pole
2. Create a plane and line it up with the pole
3. Subdivide the plane by maybe 10.
4. In edit mode, select the points on the plane that are along the pole
5. Assign them to a vertex group called "Pinned"
6. In the physics tab for the plane, create a cloth simulation
7. Under shape, select the vertex group "Pinned"
8. Turn on self collisions
9. select all faces on the plane and set shade smooth
10. Play the animation and watch it animate.
11. Adjust as needed to get the look you want.